# ROS robonaut2 control

Tags: python, ros, rospy

I make a program to control robonau2(R2).

I get a data from external publisher.

I can control R2 just one time.

'print(data.x)'   is a code to check receiving data.

Data is received successfully but R2 doesn't move... TT

How can i control R2 several times?

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python
    import sys, rospy, tf, moveit_commander, random
    from geometry_msgs.msg import Pose, Point, Quaternion
    from project_pkg.msg import arminfo

    def left_callback(data):
      orient = \
          Quaternion(*tf.transformations.quaternion_from_euler(data.phi, data.theta, data.psi)) # <1>
      pose = Pose(Point(data.x, data.y, data.z), orient)
      moveit_commander.MoveGroupCommander("left_arm").set_pose_target(pose)
      moveit_commander.MoveGroupCommander("left_arm").go(True)  
      print(data.x)

    def right_callback(data):
      orient = \
          Quaternion(*tf.transformations.quaternion_from_euler(data.phi, data.theta, data.psi)) # <1>
      pose = Pose(Point(data.x, data.y, data.z), orient)
      moveit_commander.MoveGroupCommander("right_arm").set_pose_target(pose)
      moveit_commander.MoveGroupCommander("right_arm").go(True)  
      print(data.x)


    if __name__ == '__main__':
      moveit_commander.roscpp_initialize(sys.argv)
      rospy.init_node('r2_cli',anonymous=True)
      argv = rospy.myargv(argv=sys.argv) # filter out any arguments used by ROS
      rospy.Subscriber("mat_left",arminfo,left_callback)
      rospy.Subscriber("mat_right",arminfo,right_callback)
      rospy.spin()
      moveit_commander.roscpp_shutdown()
```

and it is a example code that control R2 several times..

What is different?

```
     #!/usr/bin/env python
    import sys, rospy, tf, moveit_commander, random 
    from geometry_msgs.msg import Pose, Point, Quaternion 
    from math import pi

orient = [Quaternion(*tf.transformations.quaternion_from_euler(pi, -pi/2,   -pi/2)),Quaternion(*tf.transformations.quaternion_from_euler(pi,    -pi/2,  -pi/2))]    
pose = [Pose(Point(0.5,-0.5,1.3),orient[0]), Pose(Point(-0.5,-0.5,1.3),orient[1])]  
moveit_commander.roscpp_initialize(sys.argv)    
rospy.init_node('r2_wave_arm',anonymous=True)
group = [moveit_commander.MoveGroupCommander("left_arm"), moveit_commander.MoveGroupCommander("right_arm")]
     #  now,    wave    arms    around  randomly 

while not rospy.is_shutdown():      
   pose[0].position.x   = 0.5   + random.uniform(-0.1,  0.1)        
   pose[1].position.x = -0.5    + random.uniform(-0.1,  0.1)        
        for side in [0,1]:              
          pose[side].position.z = 1.5   + random.uniform(-0.1,  0.1)        
          group[side].set_pose_target(pose[side])   
          group[side].go(True)
moveit_commander.roscpp_shutdown()
```

Comment: The difference is you are not executing the code in a loop (e.g. inside a `while`) and thus, the code executes only once.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it to be either the publish frequency or you are receiving just a single data.

For the first, try :

```
$ rostopic echo/mat_right (or /mat_left)
```

If you are receiving messages and the robot is not moving than go to the next step (verify the frequency).

In fact, some robots have a certain frequency needed to execute the received commands. Just try to see the result of

```
$ rostopic hz /mat_right (or /mat_left)
```

and try with different frequencies using

```
$ rqt (message publisher)
```

if it starts moving only after xHz that you should publish command messages with a frequency above that value.

Hope that helps !